# Angular import for local library not resolving paths properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-auth-oidc-client

Sorry for such a noobish question.  I'm trying to compile angular-auth-oidc-client to do some contrib, but the builds aren't finding the local library.

The imports for what is supposed to be a local library are obviously not there because it's the local library I'm testing.

```
import {
  OidcSecurityService, UserDataResult } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
```

But those don't exist because they ... weren't installed by npm?

Steps to reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client.git
cd angular-auth-oidc-client
npm i
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a library in the angular.json.  I had to run one of the scripts.  Still don't like having to build it as an external source but at least I can debug.

`npm run build`